# Add lines in every /home/userxxx/public_html/.htaccess file

Tags: htaccess

I have multiple cpanel websites with this file/dir structure:

```
/home/user0/public_html/.htaccess
/home/user1/public_html/.htaccess
/home/user2/public_html/.htaccess
etc..
```

And would like to add (not just replace the whole .htaccess ) at bottom of the file couple new lines, such as:

```
#
<Files xmlrpc.php>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Files>
```

Is there a way to do that in one bulk process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You can do something like

```bash
#!/bin/sh

for f in /home/user*/public_html/.htaccess
do

   cat <<EOT >>$f
#
<Files xmlrpc.php>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Files>
EOT

done
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I saved to do that modification manually in more than 300 cpanel sites. You saved me many hours of work. Thanks soooo much :)